# How can i send a coupon generated form my website to passbook

Tags: iphone, passbook

How can I send a coupon generated form my website to passbook. Actually I send the coupon via email. I would like to provide the possibility to the user to add the coupon to the iphone's passbook.

Answer (score 7):

Have you already designed the Passbook Pass and want to share that via email, or do you just have the 'coupon details' and want to create the Passbook Pass?

If the former, configure your web server to serve the .pkpass bundles with a mime type of application/vnd.apple.pkpass

If the latter, you can use the [PassKit](http://passkit.com) Pass Designer to [create the Passbook Pass](http://create.passkit.com) and then you simply share the Pass URL in your email.

Either way, I recommend using the 'Add to Passbook' button as something that more end users are recognising. So you simply refer the URL in the 'Add to Passbook' button.

When the user clicks on this in their mail client - if they are on a mobile device, or in Safari (>Mac OSX 10.8.2) - then the Passbook coupon will display on the device screen and the user has the option to add this to the Passbook app/wallet.

As long as the customer keeps the coupon in their Passbook then you can communicate/engage with the customer via push updates to the Pass.  So you don't have to email new coupons or updates.

Disclaimer: I am one of the co-founders of PassKit

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is required that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Answer (score 3):

For a good in depth guide in how to implement 'PassBook' and using emails then I suggest looking at the following website / tutorial.

Part 1:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/20734/beginning-passbook-part-1

Part 2:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/20785/beginning-passbook-in-ios-6-part-22

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough info to give you a good answer.

However, I can point you in the right direction.  If you are running rails, check out this gem: [Passbook](https://github.com/frozon/passbook).

What you will need to do is generate a pass then have a link that downloads it with a MIME type of application/vnd.apple.pkpass. The links @KarlDaniel mentioned ([this one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20734/beginning-passbook-part-1) and [this one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20785/beginning-passbook-in-ios-6-part-22)) are also great resources.  If you update your question to be more specific, we will be able to help more.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to link direct from the browser to Passbook then you simply need to link to the .pkpass bundle and have your server serve it with a MIME type of `application/vnd.apple.pkpass`  Apple would prefer you to use their Add to Passbook button for the link anchor which can be downloaded from their [Passbook resources](http://developer.apple.com/passbook)

Note that this will only work with a Passbook compatible browser on a Passbook compatible platform (currently Safari on OSX10.8.2+  and iPhone iOS6+ or Chrome for iPhone).  For other platforms or browsers then the file will download which may confuse users. Also note that Facebook and Twitter browsers on iOS6 do not yet support browser to Passbook.